# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : When i try to remove item from list of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

When ever i try to delete last item from list it gives me IndexOutOfBound Error, its happen only with last item from list.

Here is my code

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {
    private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    private CartActivity cartActivity;
    private int total;
    public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, CartActivity cartActivity) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.cartActivity = cartActivity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cartActivity);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
    cartViewHolder.counterButton.setNumber(listData.get(i).getQuantity());
        cartViewHolder.counterButton.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
                total = 0;
                Order order = listData.get(i);
                order.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
                new Database(cartActivity).updateCart(order);
                calculate();
            }
        });

        cartViewHolder.txt_price.setText(listData.get(i).getPrice());
        cartViewHolder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(i).getFoodName());
        cartViewHolder.removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listData.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i, listData.size());
                Order order = listData.get(i);
                new Database(cartActivity).clearItem(order);
                calculate();
            }
        });
    }
    private void calculate(){
        for (Order orders: listData){
            total += Integer.parseInt(orders.getPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(orders.getQuantity());
            Log.d("GDGDGD", String.valueOf(total));
        }
        int cgst = (total * 5)/100;
        total += cgst;
        Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        cartActivity.txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
    }
}
```

Above code is snippet from recyclerview, item fetched from the database and list made.

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to learn some debugging yourself. Have you checked that for previous items the CORRECT item is removed? When your code arrives at the remove call, does it still contain items? Is the item index possibly indexed starting from 1 instead of 0 like lists? All things you can figure out to help you find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line: `Order order = listData.get(i);`

You are removing the item first and then you are trying to get the order.

```
listData.remove(i); // remove item from listData: it will have zero items if earlier, listData had one item
...
Order order = listData.get(i); // get ith order: will crash if listData's size is 0
```

Placing `listData.remove(i);` at the end of the function will solve the issue.

Like this:

```
cartViewHolder.removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notifyItemRemoved(i);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(i, listData.size());
        Order order = listData.get(i);
        new Database(cartActivity).clearItem(order);
        listData.remove(i);
        calculate();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

There is one more issue in calculate(). You have to reassign the variable `total` to zero.

Like this:

```
private void calculate(){
    total = 0;

    for (Order orders: listData){
        total += Integer.parseInt(orders.getPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(orders.getQuantity());
        Log.d("GDGDGD", String.valueOf(total));
    }
    int cgst = (total * 5)/100;
    total += cgst;
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    cartActivity.txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
}
```

And remove `total = 0;` assignment. Like this:

```
    cartViewHolder.counterButton.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            Order order = listData.get(i);
            order.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
            new Database(cartActivity).updateCart(order);
            calculate();
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinZeitler for pointing that out. Now, that issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for help, Now when i remove item total value increases.